# SQL search between two days without datetime

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Trying to search in a database a date range. Problem is, I cannot use the datetime column type in my database. To compensate, date's are displayed as three columns. a Month column, a Day column, and a Year column. Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM `import` 
 WHERE `call_day` BETWEEN 29 AND 15 
   AND `call_month` BETWEEN 9 AND 10 
   AND `call_year` BETWEEN 2013 AND 2013
```

You can see where I run into trouble. call_day needs to search between the 29th day and the 15th day. This won't work because 15 is smaller than 29, but I need it to work because the month is in the future :)

Any thoughts/solutions? No I cannot change the database in any way. Read only.

Comment: You can also use `WHERE (call_year,call_month,call_day) >= (2013,9,29) AND (call_year,call_month,call_day) <= (2013,10,15)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the concatenation approach, which can be implemented in quite a few ways, e.g.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM import
 WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', call_year, call_month, call_day), '%Y-%c-%e') 
       BETWEEN '2013-09-29' AND '2013-10-15'
```

or

```
SELECT *
  FROM import
 WHERE CONCAT(call_year, LPAD(call_month, 2, '0'), LPAD(call_day, 2, '0'))
       BETWEEN '20130929' AND '20131015'
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56d09/7)** demo

that will always cause a full scan and assuming that date ranges in your queries usually don't span more than a few months you can also do

```
SELECT *
  FROM import
 WHERE (call_year = 2013 AND 
        call_month = 9   AND 
        call_day BETWEEN 29 AND DAY(LAST_DAY('2013-09-01'))) -- or just 30
    OR (call_year = 2013 AND 
        call_month = 10 AND 
        call_day BETWEEN  1 AND 15)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7ae8/4)** demo

For a query that spans a year (e.g. from `2012-08-20` to `2013-10-15`)

```
SELECT * 
  FROM import
 WHERE (call_year = 2012 AND 
        call_month = 8 AND
        call_day BETWEEN 20 AND 31)
    OR (call_year = 2012 AND 
        call_month BETWEEN 9 AND 12 AND
        call_day BETWEEN 1 AND 31)
    OR (call_year = 2013 AND 
        call_month BETWEEN 1 AND 9 AND 
        call_day BETWEEN  1 AND 31)
    OR (call_year = 2013 AND 
        call_month = 10 AND
        call_day BETWEEN 1 AND 15)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41e9b/4)** demo

Comment: My queries may span a full year

Comment: For reference, this query worked for me:  

SELECT * 
  FROM import
 WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('/', call_year, call_month, call_day), '%Y/%c/%e') 
       BETWEEN '2013/09/29' AND '2013/10/15' (I like slashes instead of dashes :P)

Answer (score 5):

Concat the values like yyyymmdd and then you can compare them like strings.

Comment: Here's what I tried: 

    SELECT * FROM `import` WHERE CONCAT(call_year,'/',call_month,'/',call_day) BETWEEN '2013/7/29' AND '2013/10/15'

I get the same effect. that returns zero results, but if I change the day to a day BEFORE the 15th, I get results. *edited*

Comment: If your month can be stored as a single digit (as in 8 for august) this won't work. Doing betweens on char values is pretty risky. Assuming it's stored as a string, you could check the length and add a 0 to the front if it's 1 byte, but that's getting really crazy.  PeterM's suggestion may well be your best bet.

Comment: Indeed, days/months are stored as single digits. If I had BETWEEN '2013/07/29' it would return rows in january.

Answer (score 1):

As PeterM said, this may play hell with performance, but if you're storing these as integers, you can do the following:
(year * 10000) + (month* 100) + day will always yield an 8 byte "date".

```
2013 *10000 = 20130000
9 * 100 =          900
                    15
              20130915
```

It's an ugly hack, and it will be expensive, because you'll be evaluating every row in your table, if you can't limit the rows in any other way, but I think it'll work.

EDIT:
Typing is hard!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `import` 
WHERE CONCAT(CAST(`call_year`AS CHAR(4)) , RIGHT(CONCAT('00',CAST(`call_month`AS CHAR(2))),2) , RIGHT(CONCAT('00',CAST(`call_day`AS CHAR(2))),2))
BETWEEN '20130929' AND '20131015'
```